# Why Java doesn't supply a simple swap function?

Tags: java, pass-by-reference, swap, pass-by-value

Every time I want to swap two values I have to use temporary to do the actual swap. *Why doesn't Java give us a facility method in whatever class to simply swap the values of two vars?*

Comment: So what's the question? why Java haven't something for that? Ask java creators.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624525/how-to-write-a-basic-swap-function-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393906/how-do-i-make-my-swap-function-in-java

Comment: @Ademiban correct your grammar.

Comment: Can't remember the last time I actually had to swap values in real code... (except from code snippets posted to SO ;) )

Comment: @Andreas_D - one could argue that the reason you can't remember is that you are subconsciously dismissing "solutions" that would require `swap`.  :-)

Answer (score 11):

Java is [Pass-by-Value](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm). That is why you cannot create a simple swap-method [(ref)](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm).

---

You can however wrap your references inside another object and swap the internal refs:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Ref<Integer> a = new Ref<Integer>(1);
    Ref<Integer> b = new Ref<Integer>(2);

    swap(a, b);

    System.out.println(a + " " + b); // prints "2 1"
}

public static <T> void swap(Ref<T> a, Ref<T> b) {
    T tmp = a.value;
    a.value = b.value;
    b.value = tmp;
}

static class Ref<T> {
    public T value;

    public Ref(T t) {
        this.value = t;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Java does not supply such method because it is not possible. 
Variables are passed to method by value. Yes, even if these are objects. In this case we pass reference to object by value. Therefore you cannot change value of source variable inside method that received this variable as parameter:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 6;
swap(a, b);
// a is still 5, b is still 6!


void swap(int first, int second) {
    int tmp = first;
    first = second;
    second = tmp;
}
```

Comment: As mentioned elsewhere, this can be easily accomplished by wrapping the values to be swapped inside an object.