# Is it possible to write a numeric swap() function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, swap

A swap() function would result in cleaner code ([DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) than doing the work inline.  Unfortunately, the following function accomplished nothing because **in JavaScript parameters are always pass-by-value**:

```
function swap(a,b) { var temp=a; a=b; b=temp; }
```

Is there any way of writing a **function** that accomplished what this is attempting, particularly for numeric values?

I'm not impressed with the answers to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16201656/86967).
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/872433/86967) has the right idea, but doesn't handle the general case.

Comment: Are you talking about variables outside the function scope?

Comment: @jsmorph: Outside the function scope of `swap()`?  Yes.

Comment: Then you're looking for something like: `function swap(_a, _b) {a = _b; b = _a}` ?

Comment: @jsmorph: Your swap function only works if you want to modify variables named 'a' and 'b' -- not what I had in mind.

Comment: Imagine my surprise when I realized that Java, also, doesn't support this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393906/how-do-i-make-my-swap-function-in-java.  I've been spoiled by C++.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I found this approach, which isn't too bad (at least for my purposes):

```
function swap( swap_name_a, swap_name_b )
   {
   eval
      (
      "var swap_temp="+swap_name_a+";"
    + swap_name_a+"="+swap_name_b+";"
    + swap_name_b+"=swap_temp;"
      );
   }
```

You are required to quote the arguments:

```
swap('a','b');
```

It seems to also work with more complex arguments:

```
swap('list[index1]','list[index2]');
```

Note: **You will need to implement the swap() function within each scope that it will be used** because it must have access to the named arguments.  This goes against the "don't-repeat-yourself" principal, but in some circumstances it may be acceptable to copy-and-paste a bit of boilerplate code like this if it results in simplification of your algorithm logic.

---

By the way: [The example from which I derived this](http://ask.metafilter.com/170451/How-do-I-swap-two-variables-with-a-function-in-Javascript) returned the string from swap() and relied on the caller to forward the string to eval: `eval(swap('a','b'))`.  This solves the scope problem, but makes the swap operation more error prone -- and less attractive.

Be careful, that source also warned that this method could result in [taunting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9V7zbWNznbs).

---

Will time-traveling space-vampires steal your credit cards if you use `eval()`?  You should decide that for yourself, but here's some help:

- [When is JavaScript's eval() not evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil)
- [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

The biggest concern I see is that this *might* be relatively slow (depending on how the interpreter manages caching).  If it is too slow for your purposes, then don't use it.

Comment: @icktoofay: Thanks for pointing that out.  I edited my answer to address this.

Comment: Ok, now I'm really getting silly.  You could import `swap()` into functions that require it with `eval(swapfn);`, where you have previously declared `swapfn` as a global string that contains the entire function declaration for `swap()`.

Comment: This answer is not very popular so far, and _maybe_ should be avoided in production code, but it solved my problem (for use in graphics "experiments") -- and answers the question.  Tested in Chromium and Firefox.

Comment: I have run into problems when using my "import" technique with `"use strict"`.

Comment: +1, the fact that *eval* is considered *evil*, does not make the answer invalid or bad (eval is there for some reasons, this can be one if indeed one wants it to be so). The downvotes on this site can really suck!

Comment: @NikosM. Downvotes are healthy. I didn't downvote, but I don't think whoever downvoted it was wrong because it's a really bad idea to do this unless you're the only person writing code and it's not open source. Too much room for confusion for a simple swap.

Answer (score 2):

As you correctly identified, since the parameters are passed by value you cannot write a function that replaces the block:

```
var a,b;
...
var tmp = a; a = b; b = tmp;
```

However, you can do it if both are values of an object:

```
var o = {};
o.a = 3;
o.b = 4;
function swap(obj) { var tmp = obj.a; obj.a = obj.b; obj.b = tmp; }
swap(o);
```

You can also generalize the swap:

```
function swap(obj, a, b) { var tmp = obj[a]; obj[a] = obj[b]; obj[b] = tmp; }
swap(o,'a','b')
```

You can also make this a prototype function:

```
Object.prototype.swap = function(a,b) { var tmp = this[a]; this[a] = this[b]; this[b] = tmp; }
o.swap('a','b')
```

Comment: Alternatively, without an intermediate ``tmp`` var: 

``function swap(obj) { obj.a+=obj.b; obj.b=obj.a-obj.b; obj.a-=obj.b; }``

Comment: @ThalisKalfigkopoulos there are certainly many ways to do it, but the question was focusing more on the feasibility, and by sticking to the method that the OP proposed the different ways (prototype method, straight function) are more clear

Comment: Is there some way of passing the 'local scope' as your object in order to make this work with arbitrary local variables?

Comment: You can do it if you define the function within the closure (e.g. `function foo() { function swap() { var tmp = a; a = b; b = tmp; }; var a = 3, b = 7; swap(); /* here a = 7 and b = 3 */ }` but it has to be defined in the same scope and is not really much different from inlining the swap

Comment: @Nirk: I meant something like: `swap(locals,'a','b')` to be used with your generalized `swap(obj,a,b)`, but I haven't found a way to do that.

Comment: @nobar variables declared using the `var` statement aren't visible outside of the scope in which they are declared.  The only reason the inner function works is because the variables are visible to the inner function (which is being defined in a scope which can see the local variables)

Answer (score 1):

With EMCAScript 6, you can abuse the [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) feature.

```js
var x = 1, y = 2;
console.log(`x = ${x}, y = ${y}`);

[x, y] = [y, x];
console.log(`x = ${x}, y = ${y}`);
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Swapping_variables) actually has this as one of its examples.

EDIT:

Somehow I missed the bold text in the question.  If you absolutely need it to be a **function**, this kind of fits the definition (and is definitely intended as a joke):

```js
function swap() {
    return [arguments[1], arguments[0]];
}

var x = 1, y = 2;
console.log(`x = ${x}, y = ${y}`);

[x, y] = swap(x, y);
console.log(`x = ${x}, y = ${y}`);
```

Comment: Not a *function*, but probably the nicest way to do a swap in ES6.

Comment: @nobar fixed it! ;)

Answer (score -2):

To make swap(a,b) work as in C, you need references to the variables. It can be done lighter than in the above answer 1. Just

```
function swap(n, m) {
    var temp = this[n];
    this[n] = this[m];
    this[m] = temp;
  }
```

The *this* in this function is *window*, and call is *swap('a', 'b')*. Sure, you can avoid local variable *temp* with either logic or arithmetic (for *int*s).

Comment: What Is the basis for the "this" variable?