# Is it possible to swap value of two array index in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to swap two values in an array but i am unable to to it. I am creating a new swap function.
I know the value can only be swapped through referencing, but i don't know how to do it.
Can someone please help me. Below is the code i am trying to write. I want to swap the array data in class A.

```
public class test { 
public static void swap(int num[],int num2,int num3) {
   //swap code
    }
public static void main(String...args) {
    A a = new A();
    A obj1 = new A();
    A obj2 = new A();
    swap(a.num,obj1.num[0],obj2.num[2]);
}}
   class A{
        int num[]={1,2,3};
     }
```

Comment: probably duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393906/java-method-to-swap-primitives

Comment: First, share your code please, we cannot help you without it

Answer (score 3):

`int[] arr` - **arr** is reference to the array object. Therefore you can write `swap` method given this reference to swap required values.

```
public static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
    int tmp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By the way it can be done without temporary variable:

```
public static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
    arr[i] ^= arr[j];
    arr[j] ^= arr[i];
    arr[i] ^= arr[j];
}
```

Comment: Be aware that this does not work if `i == j` (this this case `array[i]` would be set to `0`)